# CDMA signal disappear after changing network using an app

Tags: settings, 4g, network-signal, gsm, cdma

My phone is a replicate of the Huawei P8 called p8 lt Dual sim Android 6.01. After I used an app called [Network Mode Universal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ljh.networkmode) to enable LTE on my phone, the signal disappear and I can't use my CDMA SIM anymore. At first, all I did was change the mode to LTE only. Then I tried other options, but nothing works. Other than that, GSM seems to work fine.

> [image]

> [image: this logs from the app]

I tried restarting my phone, resetting my network, and using another CDMA card but nothing works.

How I can reset my configuration?